# Jquery alert not showing up when dropdown list item is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get an alert to pop up when an item in a dropdown is selected, the dropdown is populated with database items. I have followed a tutorial online for the jquery part of the code where the code worked fine and the alert popped up. Just wondering if anyone can help as to why its not working with my code? (the ajax part has nothing to do with my question)

```
            $(document).on('click', '.theclass', function() {
                var clicked = $(this).attr("id"); 
                alert(clicked);
            });

            });

    </script>
```

Comment: `dataType: "php",` should be `dataType: "html",` and you should uncomment the line for the alert. Also, show us the HTML. Your event handler should also be `change`, not `click`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus ive edited the code, the alert im trying to get to work is the top one not the ajax alert!

Comment: How do the AJAX and PHP tags apply here? I see nothing AJAXy about this.

Comment: Can you post the resulting page instead of PHP code ? A sample fiddle I made seems to be working https://jsfiddle.net/g7oq6ynw/4/

Comment: See my updated (again) answer. You are using a single `<script>` element to reference JQuery and to embed your code. You also have an extra `});` in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

**You cannot link to an external JavaScript source library AND embed your own JavaScript in a single `<script>` element.** You must use two `<script>` elements, like this:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"><script>

 <script>
        $(document).on('click', '.studentclass', function() {
            var clickeditem = $(this).attr("id"); 
            alert(clickeditem);
        });
</script>
```

Also, your code includes an extra `});` at the end, which is a **syntax error**.

Next, **because you are dynamically creating the element**, it may be that the code to wire up the event handler is running before the element has been added to the DOM. In that case, **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** is recommended. Even if the current code creates the element before the script runs, this is considered a best-practice to guard against this becoming a problem in the future, should your code structure change.

As the beginning of that article states:

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
>   selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
>   future.

Change your code to:

```
$(document).on("click", ".studentclass", function() {
  var clickeditem = $(this).attr("id"); 
  alert(clickeditem);
});
```

Since we can't reproduce .php here, **I'll show the working code** with a static element.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.studentclass', function() {
  var clickeditem = $(this).attr("id"); 
  alert(clickeditem);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Find Student ></button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
      <div id="studentdrop">
       <div id='students1'>
          <a href="#" id="testing1" class="studentclass">student name</a>
       </div>
       <div id='students2'>
          <a href="#" id="testing2" class="studentclass">student name</a>
       </div>       
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As seen from the code, the elements seem to exist when page is created (it's PHP)

Comment: Ya my code is all the same as that but it still doesnt work, it must be something to do with the php side of things

Comment: @Jub The code in your question has two major syntax errors as I describe in my answer.